# Reach a nested javascript function from another one (beginner inside)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I use a slideshow system I found over the internet and I try to tweak it a little bit.
There are two js files there and each one of them is made of functions like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.file1 = function(data, vData) 
    {
       //function aaa
       //function bbb
       //function ccc
    }
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
    $.file2 = function(data, vData) 
    {
       //function eee
       //function fff
       //function gig
    }
})(jQuery);
```

How can I trigger function eee from inside function bbb?

I tried these from inside the bbb function but it didn't work:

```
eee();
$.file2.eee();
```

I'm not trying to return a variable, I just need the function triggered.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have to make the function somehow accessible from the outside, e.g. by assigning it to a variable in a shared scope. But this would require that `$.file1` runs before `$.file2`. It would be cleaner if you'd define `eee` outside `$.file1`.

Comment: do `$.file1` and `$.file2` return anything, rather, are they constructors for creating objects which have `aaa`, `bbb`, etc. methods attached to them?

Comment: Felix: Can you be more specific please? How can I assign it from outside as you suggest it? Than you for your help sir. jackwanders: no they don't return anything. They don't seem to be constructors of any objects.

Comment: Define a variable in a scope accessible to both functions `var someVar;` and assign the function `someVar = eee;` to it. Just simple variable assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to expose the functions to other scopes:

```
(function($) {
    $.file1 = function(data, vData) {
       //function aaa
       //function bbb
       //function ccc
       return {
           aaa: aaa,
           bbb: bbb,
           ccc: ccc
       };
    }
})(jQuery);

$.file1().aaa();
$.file1().bbb();
$.file1().ccc();
```

Note that this is a pretty awkward pattern for defining functions. It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish with this pattern. You might be better off using an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
var thing = (function($) {
    //function aaa
    //function bbb
    //function ccc

    return {
        aaa: aaa,
        bbb: bbb,
        ccc: ccc
    };
})(jQuery);

thing.aaa();
thing.bbb();
thing.ccc();
```

Comment: You'd have to call `$.file1` first: `$.file1 = $.file1()` or execute the function immediately.

Comment: Thank you I tried it all with no success. The function doesn't fire.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to thank you all for your help.

What I did is this: 
Inside the calling function bbb (in file 2), I added this:

```
$.file1.triggerEee();
```

Inside the main function of file 1 ($.file1) I added this:

```
$.file1.triggerEee=function(){eee();};
```

It did the trick.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

inside those two function jquery calls just reference the methods, don't implement it there. If you implement it elsewhere it will be extremely easy to reference.

Comment: Ok but that's the point, I'm just trying to tweak a script which is not mine. In one file there is a function which detects when a video is over; on the other file there is a function which removes a lightbox. My point is to remove the lightbox when the video is over. Easy to say and normally easy to achieve but there is no global function I can use from outside these methods so I'm stuck.

Comment: I'm assuming you're able to edit this code even though you didn't write it.. It would be messy but consider copying over methods into each file? That, or else start refactoring the code. Immensely.

Comment: I thought of it and I don't mind working a little bit but this script is quite complex as no method is standalone. Each one of them is made of methods and variables made of other methods or variables and lot of them are dynamic. This makes them very very very tricky to isolate. But I found a workaround now so it's ok. Thank you very much for your concern and your help.